# Getting the IoT Edge Module Settings

Tags: azure-iot-edge

In the Azure portal, you can see the "IoT Edge Module Settings" :

[image]

How do I access this programatically from C#?

When I get the list of modules on the edge device, there doesn't appear to be an option to get the settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the Microsoft Azure Devices Client SDK/package and attack it this way:

```
var registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connString); //the connection string for your IOT Hub
var moduleTwins= new List<Twin>();
//var query = registryManager.CreateQuery($"SELECT * FROM devices", 100);
var query = registryManager.CreateQuery("SELECT * FROM devices.modules WHERE deviceId='MyEdgeDevice'",100);
while (query.HasMoreResults) {
    var page = await query.GetNextAsTwinAsync();
    moduleTwins.AddRange(page);
}

// this gets rid of all that version/metadata noise in a module/device twin
foreach (var module in moduleTwins) {
    module.Properties.Reported.ClearMetadata();
    module.Properties.Desired.ClearMetadata();
}
```

Now `moduleTwins` is now an enumerable list of the Twin object (which is a direct representation of module/device twins).   As a fun aside, in there will also be $edgeAgent and $edgeHub twins -- which contain *everything* - and in the list of `modules` for edgeAgent, you'll see more of that information for each module (the image, create options, restart policy, etc), which is found in $edgeAgent's `properties.desired.modules` area

```
   "modules": {
      "MyNeatModule": {
        "type": "docker",
        "settings": {
          "image": "myAzureContainerRegistry.io/myneatmodule:amd64.debug",
          "createOptions": "{}"
        },
        "status": "running",
        "restartPolicy": "always",
        "version": "1.0"
      },
```

and everything you're looking for is in $edgeAgent's `properties.reported` area:

```
"modules": {
          "SuperNeatAwesomeModule": {
            "exitCode": 0,
            "statusDescription": "running",
            "lastStartTimeUtc": "2018-11-01T18:39:09.8814806Z",
            "lastExitTimeUtc": "2018-11-01T18:05:40.8350456Z",
            "restartCount": 0,
            "lastRestartTimeUtc": "2018-11-01T18:05:40.8350456Z",
            "runtimeStatus": "running",
            "version": "1.0",
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "type": "docker",
            "settings": {
              "image": "blahblahblah.azurecr.io/superneatmodule:0.0.2-amd64.debug",
              "imageHash": "sha256:ladkjsfaldkjfasdflkjasdfljasfljkasflja4",
              "createOptions": "{}",
              "env":{}
```